# Microsoft.Build Not Rebuilding Properly

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-4.0

We're modifying an app that rebuilds everything in a Visual Studio solution. We were using BuildEngine but since it's deprecated, we're moving to Microsoft.Build.

The code is like this:

```
var projectCollection = new Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection();
var globalProperty = new Dictionary<String, String>();
var buildRequest = new Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildRequestData(Directory.GetFiles(@"Build\", "*.sln").First(), globalProperty, null, new String[] { "Clean", "Build" }, null);

Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(new Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildParameters(projectCollection), buildRequest);

// 2nd time's a charm?
// Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(new Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildParameters(projectCollection), buildRequest);
```

But the projects are not being rebuilt. However, if the Build method is run twice (as the commented code above), the projects are rebuilt properly.

Comment: I've been fighting the same problem, mate. Not sure if it makes a difference, but I'm trying to re-build an MVC project after adding a controller to it (as a file and an entry in the .csproj file).

I did try your "2nd time's the charm" approach, but without success - the exactly same DLL was generated.

I also tried removing the contents of the "bin" and "obj" folders before rebuilding, but the same DLL was placed as if nothing in the project had changed.

Looking forward to some suggested solutions!